# Swift/Xcode6: Are PDF images working with UIImage(named:)?

Tags: ios, pdf, swift, asset-catalog

I have an app with a lot of PDF/Vector assets to be used as images in UIImageViews. Putting them into UIImageViews in Storyboard/Interface Builder works perfectly, but
    UIImage(named: "test")
always returns nil.

Since I have found nothing on the topic, except that it should work, I was wondering if there was anything special to consider?

Comment: [here](http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/) for example.

Xcode generates PNGs from the PDF asset at build time. These can be used in Storyboard/IB, but don't seem to work from code.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted as I am looking for a similar answer. In the apple asset catalog docs(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html) it says "You can use that name to programmatically load any individual image contained in the set. To load an image, call the platform specific class method, passing in the name of the set that contains the image. The OS will load the image from the set that is most appropriate for the current scale factor. The platform method for iOS is imageNamed:. "

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where your asset catalog is being stored, you may have to explicitly point to its enclosing bundle. If your `UIImage(named: "test")` is returning nil, try instead:

```
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.classForCoder)
let image = UIImage(named: imageName, inBundle: bundle, compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil)
```

This will look for the image in the same bundle as the class where you are requesting the image.

HTH